# Enabling two selector menus for cartodb webmap?

Tags: carto, layers, html

I am trying to enable two selector menu dropdowns within a webmap pulling data from the same cartodb table. Each drop down is for a different type of route I would like to select. The top selector menu is working as it should, however, the second is not functioning. Am I missing something to enable the second selector? Link to web map and code below.

http://garscube.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Garsube Harriers Training Routes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/isotope.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsive-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/skin.css">  
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }



      #selector_menu1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 125px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index: 9000;
        border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#0099ff; background-color:#ffffff; padding: .25em;  
      }
      #selector_menu2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 165px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index: 9000;
        border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#0099ff; background-color:#ffffff; padding: .25em;  
      }

        #maptitle{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 20px;
        }  

    #maptitleborder{
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#287EC7;
} 



    </style>
    <!-- include cartodb css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>

<div class="header">
    <section id="header" class="appear">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-0="line-height:100px; height:100px; background-color:rgba(0,7,45,0.5);" data-300="line-height:60px; height:60px; background-color:rgba(0,7,45,.7);">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="fa fa-bars color-white"></span>
                </button>
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.garscubeharriers.org.uk/" data-0="line-height:95px;" data-300="line-height:55px;">Garscube Harriers Routes
                </a></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-0="margin-top:26px;" data-300="margin-top:8px;">
                    <li><a href="#about">INTERVAL SESSIONS</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#work">PACK SESSIONS</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>    
<!--<div id="maptitle">
    <h1 style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:#0099ff; background-color:#ffffff; padding: .5em;">Garscube Thursday Routes</h1>
</div>-->

<div id='selector_menu1'>
        <select id='selector'>
            <option value='interval'>Select Interval Session</option>
            <option value='AR400'>Anniesland Road 400m</option>
            <option value = 'AR600'>Anniesland Road 600m</option>
        </select>

    </div>  

 <div id='selector_menu2'>
        <select id='selector'>
            <option value='pack'>Select Pack Session</option>
            <option value='layer1'>5.6m – QMD to Esquire House</option>
            <option value = 'layer2'>6.2m  – Canal/ Almond Road</option>
        </select>

    </div>      
    <script>

        function init(){

            var sublayer;
            // create leaflet map and define some properties
        var map = L.map('map', { 
          zoomControl: false,
          center: [55.894967, -4.313957],
          zoom: 13
        })

        var marker = L.marker([55.902764, -4.316062]).addTo(map);

        // add a base layer to map
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>' }).addTo(map);

            var layerUrl = 'https://smitty1788.carto.com/api/v2/viz/7eb2e59e-743e-11e6-b392-0e233c30368f/viz.json' ;
            cartodb.createLayer(map,layerUrl)
                .addTo(map)
                .on('done', function(layer){
                    sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

                    var LayerActions = {
                        pack: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0;line-opacity: 0;}");
                        },
                        layer1: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 1");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
                            return true;
                        },
                        layer2: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 2");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
                            return true;
                            ;
                        },

                        interval: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0;line-opacity: 0;}");
                        },
                        AR400: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 3");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
                            return true;
                        },
                        AR600: function(){
                            sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 4");
                            sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
                            return true;
                            ;
                        } 
                    }

                $('#selector').change(function() {
                     LayerActions[$(this).val()]();
                }); 

                });
        }


        window.onload = init;

    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two different dropdown menus, you need to give them two different `id`s attributes:

```
<div id='selector_menu1'>
    <select id='selector'>
        <option value='interval' selected>Select Interval Session</option>
        <option value='AR400'>Anniesland Road 400m</option>
        <option value = 'AR600'>Anniesland Road 600m</option>
    </select>
</div>  

<div id='selector_menu2'>
    <select id='selector2'>
        <option value='pack' selected>Select Pack Session</option>
        <option value='layer1'>5.6m – QMD to Esquire House</option>
        <option value = 'layer2'>6.2m  – Canal/ Almond Road</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Similarly, you have to create two different `LayerActions` variables:

```
var LayerActions2 = {
    pack: function(){
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0;line-opacity: 0;}");
    },
    layer1: function(){
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 1");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
        return true;
    },
    layer2: function(){
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 2");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
        return true;
    }

}

var LayerActions = {
    interval: function(){
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0;line-opacity: 0;}");
        console.log('hola');
    },
    AR400: function(){
        console.log('hola');
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 3");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
        return true;
    },
    AR600: function(){
        console.log('hola');
        sublayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE objectid = 4");
        sublayer.setCartoCSS("#routes {line-color: #1f78b4; line-width: 4; line-opacity: 0.7;}");
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Finally, you have to associate the first with the second via JQuery:

```
$('#selector').change(function() {
     LayerActions[$(this).val()]();
}); 

$('#selector2').change(function() {
     LayerActions2[$(this).val()]();
});
```

If you replace your code with mine should work. But I have also checked that your `routes` dataset only contains 2 rows (`objectid`s `1` and `2`), so you will not get any result when implementing the first dropdown.

Comment: ramiroaznar Thank you so much! I will try this out today and make sure I implement the changes correctly. I am slowly adding more data to the routes dataset, which will end up with roughly 15 rows once all is said and done. I am still new to web mapping so I am slowly learning what I am sure are basic lessons to the more experienced out there.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please, mark my answer as correct if you think your question is solved.